# Swagger 'no operation define in spec' ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

My swagger display shown no sign of any Controller. I don't know what's wrong with my setup. Everything was easy for previous version but I struggle at 3.1. I have tried giving [ApiAttribute] to my Controller but they return another error 'Controller does not have any attribute'.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     SetupSwagger(services);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseSwagger();
}

    private void SetupSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DemoAuth", Version = "v1" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {

                Description = Constants.JWT_DESCRIPTION,
                Name = Constants.AUTHORIZATION,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = Constants.BEARER
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement(){
              {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                     {
                          Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                              Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                              Id = Constants.BEARER
                            },
                            Scheme = Constants.OAUTH2,
                            Name = Constants.BEARER,
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                      },
                      new List<string>()
              }
            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: How do you configure the Swagger UI, and can you share the apicontroller?

Comment: It just a normal controller file. I try adding Api Attribute but it return me with error that this controller has no such attribute.

Comment: If the controller has no action, it will prompt this error.

Comment: You mean something  like [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]? I just try adding a few it still not working.

Comment: How do you configure swagger ui, can you show it?

Comment: Does the setting I posted in my question is not enough? Cause that's all I have.

Comment: But it has no error after I confiure the swaggerui.

Comment: I just figure out why. I didn't set [Route("api/controller")] for my controller. But after I set it, it return me with new error "undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json"

Comment: Please check the version in `c.SwaggerDoc("v1"...`. Make sure they are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue for the last two days. I was having two methods with the same HttpGet calls.

You can look for the error details in out put window.

[image]